# Trouble with Extract Number from a string

Tags: regexp-replace

The decimal point is being removed in the ExtractNumber.  I cannot determine cause.

IE:  .25MP returns 25 and not .25

```
Public Function ExtractNumber(inValue As String) As Variant
With New RegExp
.Pattern = "(\d{1,3},?)+(\.\d{2})?"
.Global = True
If .test(inValue) Then
ExtractNumber = CDec(.Execute(inValue)(0))
dNumericFromRange = ExtractNumber
End If
End With
End Function
```

Have tried...

```
ExtractNumber = CDbl(.Execute(inValue)(0))
ExtractNumber = CVar(.Execute(inValue)(0))
```

Comment: Could you not convert it from a string into a decimal first so that its not a string but a numerical value you are considering?

Comment: That is because `(\d{1,3},?)+` is not optional, the `+` means 1 or more times. Maybe something like `\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?` See the matches https://regex101.com/r/Rn6R0C/1

Comment: The [Val function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: That is because (\d{1,3},?)+ is not optional, the + means 1 or more times. Maybe something like \.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})? See the matches regex101.com/r/Rn6R0C/1 – 
The fourth bird
 Wow!  thanks so much!  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I wonder if I could trouble you one more time as I do not get this. Frustrating.  IE:  1500MB returns 150 and  not 1500.

Comment: @MvG In that case you could write it like this `\.\d{1,2}|\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?` https://regex101.com/r/cpHYec/1